Cannot run React in docker with Yarn 4 because of missing `react-scripts` packages, but works well natively (without docker)
I create a new ReactTs project from scratch, with Yarn 4.4.1 (Just started using yarn 4).
I created the project with the Create React App Client:
# In my /frontend directory
yarn create react-app . --template typescript

When running natively with yarn start , it works like a charm (Well, not really. I got some errors related to the /frontend/src/App.test.tsx file, but this isn't related to my actual issue so I just commented it out for now -> Edit: It has been solved here #13585).
Edit: I have tried using npm and yarn 1 instead of yarn 4 and it works, even within the docker container.
But when I run it with Docker, I get this error:
Attaching to web-1
web-1  | 
web-1  | node:internal/modules/run_main:129
web-1  |     triggerUncaughtException(
web-1  |     ^
web-1  | Error: Required package missing from disk. If you keep your packages inside your repository then restarting the Node process may be enough. Otherwise, try to run an install first.
web-1  | 
web-1  | Missing package: react-scripts@virtual:d9650954c7f1725ea712d2e40695de9ea5d1c0fa9b89379134c62909d440d91b03d6c37e2823804a3404472b90a5bec73c82193190dd3c4db4c9e9edd75db91e#npm:5.0.1
web-1  | Expected package location: /app/.yarn/__virtual__/react-scripts-virtual-f2aa641dfb/5/.yarn/berry/cache/react-scripts-npm-5.0.1-d06bd2d5ad-10c0.zip/node_modules/react-scripts/
web-1  | 
web-1  |     at makeError (/app/.pnp.cjs:23863:34)
web-1  |     at resolveUnqualified (/app/.pnp.cjs:25584:17)
web-1  |     at resolveRequest (/app/.pnp.cjs:25635:14)
web-1  |     at Object.resolveRequest (/app/.pnp.cjs:25691:26)
web-1  |     at resolve$1 (file:///app/.pnp.loader.mjs:2043:21)
web-1  |     at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:866:28)
web-1  |     at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:304:30)
web-1  |     at MessagePort.handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:196:24)
web-1  |     at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:820:20)
web-1  |     at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
web-1  | 
web-1  | Node.js v20.17.0
web-1 exited with code 1

When I inspect my container with the following command:
docker compose run --rm web yarn info react-scripts

react-scripts are actually installed. But I still get the same error when running a yarn start from inside the container.
Here is my compose.yml file:
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./frontend
        target: /app

      - type: volume
        source: frontend.node_modules
        target: /app/node_modules

volumes:
  frontend.node_modules:

And my frontend/Dockerfile.development file:
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate

COPY . .

RUN yarn install --immutable

CMD ["yarn", "start"]


As a first step I'd delete all of the volumes: blocks: they mean you're not actually running the code in the image, and so you can get unpredictable results that way.  Naming the Dockerfile just Dockerfile will also allow you to have a shorter build: syntax.  What's the actual error you get?

Volumes are needed because of React hot-reload. And I don't want to put node modules in the code base, even if they are untracked. Dockerfile has been named as it is because other Dockerfiles will be added later. Haven't got issues on my previous React-Docker projects. The difference here is that I migrated from yarn 1 to yarn 4 (And I went from React (Js) 17 to (Ts) 18)

It sounds like you already have a working setup build on Node and Yarn, which is normally what I'd recommend.  What benefits are you hoping to get from running in Docker, if you're actively trying to avoid immutable images?

Different devs works on different versions of different environments. The purpose is to just run docker compose up and to have a working environment, no matter on which OS you are. Also, docker is (almost) completely isolated from your OS, which make it easier to restore if you break your environment or if you made a mess out of it. And finally, the production artifacts are quite close to the dev ones.

im going to guess the package is globally installed on the desktop so it needs to be explicitly installed in the docker image.

Nope. The packages missing (react-scripts) are in the package.json file. Furthermore, it works with yarn 1 and npm (both inside docker). It also works with yarn 4 directly on the host.

The whole /app/.yarn/__virtual__/ stuff smells like yarn pnp is failing – maybe disable it within the container build?

@AKX I just found a solution and yes, PnP was the issue. I answered to the question. Thanks for your help though.

Investigating more into Yarn 4 (and Yarn Berry, generally speaking), I've found where the issue is, and it's mainly because of my misunderstanding of how Yarn Berry PnP works:
The issue was that Node inside the Docker container couldn't resolve package dependencies managed by Yarn's Plug'n'Play (PnP). The .pnp.cjs file (generated by the CRA client), which Yarn uses to map dependencies, wasn't being automatically loaded.
I added the following environment variable in my frontend/Dockerfile.development:
# ...
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--require ./.pnp.cjs"  # Add this

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

The NODE_OPTIONS environment variable ensures that Node (inside the container) loads the .pnp.cjs file on startup, enabling it to resolve dependencies correctly using Yarn PnP.
PnP being the default installation strategy of Yarn Berry (Yarn 2+), while Yarn 1 used node_modules.
There seems to be different installation modes you can enforce by adding it to the .yarnrc.yml config file such as:
nodeLinker: node-modules

I haven't explored those yet but I prefer using PnP instead. Seems more powerfull.
